# React child component receiving props as undefined

Tags: lodash, reactjs

I have component `Comp1` and it's child `Comp2`. The state of `markers` is set in the parent component to this object:

```
    var MARKER_ITEMS = {
            "item1" : {
                  "cat" : "wow",
                  "img" : "slide",
                  "info" : "bike",
                  "key" : "1"
                },
                "item2" : {
                  "cat" : "omg",
                  "img" : "slide",
                  "info" : "4x4",
                  "key" : "2"
                }
        };
```

When I try to generate a `Comp2` for each object with loadash `_.map`, the props get passed down as undefined.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luandro/fstf71gm/39/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works but you're using the `key` name as a props. `key` is a special reserved property name that React uses in order to know which dynamic children a component has.

If you switch from `key` to `stuff` for example, your code will work.

[Read here about it](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children) and [here](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/special-non-dom-attributes.html)