# React props not received in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My Component:

```
class Translate extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    key: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    replacements: React.PropTypes.array
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.debug('PROPS', props); // Prints empty object

    this.state = props;
  }

..
}
```

Which is imported in another component and used in JSX like this:

```
import Translate from '/path/to/translate';

...

<Translate key='someKey' />
```

Why is key not received in props? I have a lot of other components who do the same, and I don't get what's wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it. I simply can't use "key" as a props element (which I got from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/28826149/1101897). Using anything else (e.g. "message") works.